# Programming an AVR using ISP

Tags: avr, isp

I am trying to program an atmega with arduino sketch using ISP only (mac user).
So I know how to burn a boot loader, and then to program the chip using the TX, RX. But I would like to program it directly using ISP, without a boot loader.
So I am using the UNO as a ISP programmer, and trying without success to program a chip on a PCB:

1. I upload to the UNO the ArduinoISP sketch
2. Connect the lines to the target board (target board have atmega328, crystal, capacitors, LED)
3. Choose the board "Arduino pro or pro mini" in the Arduino IDE.
4. Choose the programmer- "Arduino as ISP"
5. At the beginning I tried to upload a boot loader, to see if its going well, it DID boot loaded the chip,so I know the connections are good, and I am set to go.

**Now, I am trying to just upload a sketch using the SAME ISP connection, I didn't touch anything(!)** , so I opened the blinking example, hit the upload button, and it's just not working (not in sync).

Again, the goal is now to program a chip with ISP directly, without a boot loader. The reason I boot loaded it is to see it's all connected well.

I can't imagine how the exact same configuration can bootload the chip,and later can't upload a sketch directly using the ISP.

What am I missing here? Can't you use the Arduino IDE to upload a sketch directly as an ISP programmer?

Comment: Just buy something an like AVR ISP mk2. I think its silly to go tru the hassle of implementing your own ISP when you can buy one for 20€.

Comment: i have one , and have the same problem!

Comment: Try this: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=118089.0

Comment: Agreed, this is off-topic for EESE.  But FWIW, what you're doing should of course be possible (program the device with just your sketch & no bootloader), and the fact that you can burn just a bootloader but not the sketch *might* mean your electrical connections are ok, so my next suggestion would be to confirm that your target hardware is in fact a Pro or Pro-Mini or very compatible to it. Fuse settings of course vary from one platform to another...

Comment: Usually I would recommend using Atmel Studio for development on AVRs because it's so easy to use; but I don't think you can install it for Mac. However I did use the avr-gcc toolchain in command prompt for Linux machines once. Maybe it'll help: http://www.instructables.com/id/Getting-Started-with-Embedded-Systems-using-Atmel/step5/Uploading-Code-to-the-MCU-with-Linux/

Comment: Uploading the bootloader probably changed the fuse settings. Try connecting a crystal to the chip.

Comment: Are you clicking "File>Upload using programmer" to upload?

Answer (score 1):

You probably used a direct upload button that uses default Arduino programming using RX TX, not the programmer you had selected.

All wirings are perfect that's why you were able to burn the bootloader.

Now you just need to go under **Sketch -> Upload Using Programmer.**